# Split string on newline and write it into array using read

Tags: bash, string, array

Given string `foo`, I want to store each of its field seperated by `\n` into elements of array `bar`. And I want to do this using `read` command, or any other command that is compatible with older versions of bash (which `readarray` isn't).

I tried this command:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a bar <<< "$foo"
```

but it just returns error code 1.

Is there any command that I can use to accomplish what I want? I know I could do this iteratively but obviously just doing it with one command is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is returning 1 because the delimiter is not seen in the string. However, the array is populated:

```bsh
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
3.2.57(1)-release
$ foo=$'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour'

$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a bar <<<"$foo"
$ echo $?
1
$ declare -p bar
declare -a bar='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four")'
```

Using a non-null delimiter produces a non-zero result:

```bsh
$ unset bar
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d "\034" -r -a bar <<<"${foo}\034"
$ echo $?
0
$ declare -p bar
declare -a bar='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four")'
```

Octal 34 is the ASCII "file separator" character, and is *unlikely* to be present in your data.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly shorter variant of @glenn jackman's first solution: given

```bash
foo=$'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour'
```

, we let Bash do *all* the work:

```bash
set -o noglob         # See special Note, below.
IFS=$'\n' bar=($foo)
set +o noglob         # See special Note, below.
```

The parentheses tell Bash that we are initializing an array, whose elements are what's inside the parentheses.  That's it, done.

> *Edited to add*       **Note:** if input lines could contain globbing metacharacters like `*` or `?` (`man 7 glob` has the full list), then we must guard against filename expansion; by, for example, temporarily disabling `noglob`.  Thank you for catching that, Gordon Davisson!

---

---

Confirm that worked:

```bash
echo ${#bar[@]}
```

```
4
```

, and

```bash
echo "[0]:'${bar[0]}' ... [3]:'${bar[3]}'"
```

```
[0]:'one' ... [3]:'four'
```

---

---

```bash
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
```

```
4.1.2(2)-release
```

Comment: This can fail if any of the lines look like filename wildcards. For example, if there's a line consisting just of "*", it'll be replaced by a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: Well caught; thank you!  To guard against that eventuality, we can temporarily disable `noglob`.  Editing...